# SQL command not properly ended error while filtering gridview on checkboxlist select

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, gridview

I am trying to filter my `gridview` on the basis of `checkboxlist` selected.

So here is what I tried

```
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConn"].ConnectionString;
    string strQuery = "select sr_no, type, stage, ref_no, ref_date, party_name, amount, remarks, exp_type, " +
                        "voucher_no, cheque_no,cheque_dt, chq_favr_name from XXCUS.XXACL_PN_EXPENSE_INFO";

    string condition = string.Empty;

    foreach (ListItem li in ddlStatus.Items)
    {
        condition += li.Selected ? string.Format("'{0}',", li.Value) : string.Empty;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(condition))
        {
            condition += string.Format(" Where type IN ({0})", condition.Substring(0, condition.Length - 1));
        }

        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(constr))
        {
            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(strQuery + condition))
            {
                using (OracleDataAdapter sda = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    using (DataTable dtcheck = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dtcheck);
                        GridExpInfo.DataSource = dtcheck;
                        GridExpInfo.DataBind();
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

but I am getting error as

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

My debugged query is

```
select sr_no, type, stage, ref_no, ref_date, party_name, amount, remarks, exp_type, voucher_no, cheque_no,cheque_dt, chq_favr_name 
from XXCUS.XXACL_PN_EXPENSE_INFO'10', 
Where type IN ('10')
```

I took reference from [here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Filter-GridView-using-CheckBoxList-CheckBoxes-in-ASPNet.aspx)

Comment: there's a comma before WHERE

Comment: @Aleksej: how does it is coming, In my code It is not written anwhere before `WHERE` ?

Comment: @nad May be you're adding here `string.Format("'{0}',",`

Comment: The `'10',` between the table name and the `where` is caused by the `condition += li.Selected ? string.Format("'{0}',", li.Value) : string.Empty;`

Comment: @Div: it is as same written in the reference link which I gaved.

Comment: @MartinSchapendonk: any idea on how to tackle this ? I am not hard coding that `,` anywhere.

Comment: Yes, you did hard code that. `"'{0}',"` generates `'10',`, which is in your query.

Answer (score 0):

You should prepare the where condition using a List of strings and run the query after you have completed the query builder phase.

```
// Create a list of your conditions to put inside the IN statement
List<string>conditions = new List<string>();
foreach (ListItem li in ddlStatus.Items)
{
    if(li.Selected) 
       conditions.Add($"'{li.Value}'");
} 

// Now build the where condition used
string whereCondition = string.Empty;
if (condition.Count > 0)
{
    // This produces something like "WHERE type in ('10', '11', '12')"
    // The values for the IN are directly concatenated together
    whereCondition = " Where type IN (" + string.Join(",", conditions) + ")";
}

using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(constr))
{
    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(strQuery + whereCondition))
    {
       ....
```

Consider that this approach is very exposed to [Sql Injection attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) and to a parsing problems if your selected values are strings containing quotes

Instead if you start using parameters then your code should be changed to

```
int count = 1;
List<OracleParameter> parameters = new List<OracleParameter>();
List<string>conditions = new List<string>();
foreach (ListItem li in ddlStatus.Items)
{
    if(li.Selected) 
    {
       // parameters are named :p1, :p2, :p3 etc...
       conditions.Add($":p{count}");

       // Prepare a parameter with the same name of its placeholder and
       // with the exact datatype expected by the column Type, assign to
       // it the value and add the parameter to the list
       OracleParameter p = new OracleParameter($":p{count}",OracleType.NVarChar);
       p.Value = li.Value;
       parameters.Add(p);
       count ++;
    }
} 
if (condition.Count > 0)
{
    // This produces something like "WHERE type in (:p1, :p2, :p3)"
    // The values are stored before in the parameter list
    whereCondition = " Where type IN (" + string.Join(",", conditions) + ")";
}

using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(constr))
{
    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(strQuery + whereCondition))
    {
       // Add the parameters with the expected names, type and value.
       cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());
       ....
```

It is a little more lines but this prevents Sql Injection and there is no more problem in parsing strings

Comment: If the project was mine I would use the parameters approach. It is more safe. However if you are absolutely sure that your listbox values are not coming from user input and there are no quotes embedded then also the first approach could work. But why compromise on this? Use parameters always and never string concatenation is a better mindset.

Comment: okay, I am using second approach. but getting error as `) expected` at line `conditions.Add($":p{i}");`

Comment: my bad, it is count not i

Comment: how should I define parameters in oracle, sorry but I am confused that how to do it in oracle ?

Comment: Like any other variable. You have alread defined the OracleConnection and other variables from the Oracle namespace so you shouldn't have any problem in declaring and initializing an OracleParameter like above. Did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126138/discussion-between-nad-and-steve).